# Overdamped vs Underdamped Langevin

Tags: mathematical-modeling, stochastic-differential-equations, stationary-processes, statistical-mechanics, hamilton-equations

Consider the :

$\textbf{Underdamped Langevin}$

\begin{align}
dX_t&=V_tdt
\\
\frac{m}{\gamma}dV_t&=-V_tdt-\nabla \phi(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2D} W_t.
\end{align}

I believe $m$ is the mass, $\gamma$ constant of friction, and $D$ diffusion\temperature constant.

$\textbf{Overdamped Langevin}$

\begin{align}
dX_t&=-\nabla \phi(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2D} W_t.
\end{align}

What are the fundamental 1) modelling differences 2) mathematical differences between these equations?

Edit : I was a bit confused by this question and answer since it says we should NOT interpret this as sending the friction to $\infty$: [Average velocity of overdamped particles in external field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726694/average-velocity-of-overdamped-particles-in-external-field/3737450#3737450)

Comment: The reason it is not the same as setting the friction to be very large is that  the "over damped" SDE is now of first order ( only first derivative of velocity). Taking the limit of a small second order derivative is singular, and may lead to subtle effects near boundaries ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation for an example).

Comment: related PhysicsSE questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695721/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556859/226902